# Rails 3 using select distinct

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select, distinct

I have 3 tables I need to join together.

I have `Events`, `Places`, and `Boroughs`

Places belong to a Borough and have many Events

From a list of events on a given day, I would like to retrieve a list of all the distinct boroughs.

```
Event.where(day_of_week: 2).joins(:place,:borough).select("DISTINCT(boroughs.name) AS name")
```

Generating the SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(boroughs.name) AS name FROM "events" INNER JOIN "places" ON "places"."id" =        
"events"."place_id" INNER JOIN "places" "places_events_join" ON "places_events_join"."id" = 
"events"."place_id" INNER JOIN "boroughs" ON "boroughs"."id" = 
"places_events_join"."borough_id" WHERE "events"."active" = 't' AND "events"."day_of_week" = 3
```

Which looks perfect and works when I throw it into my postgres DB console, however for my rails console I get.

```
#<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >
```

UPDATE:

Mr.The Walrus' suggestion works perfectly, but I'm still confused why going the other way around doesn't work when the SQL itself produces the same result.

```
Borough.joins(:events).where(:events => {:day_of_week => 2}).select("DISTINCT(boroughs.name) AS name")
```

Produces:

```
[#<Borough name: "richmond">, #<Borough name: "southwark">, #<Borough name: "brent">, #<Borough name: "city of london">]
```

But this

```
Event.where(:events => {:day_of_week => 2}).joins(:borough).select("DISTINCT(boroughs.name) AS name")
```

Produces:

```
[#<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to name your column or else ActiveRecord won't know how to map it.

```
Event.where(day_of_week: 2).joins(:place,:borough).select('DISTINCT(boroughs.name) as "bouroughs.name"')
```

Comment: actually I tried that.  Still get [#<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >, #<Event >]

Comment: Oh if you're using a join you might need to fully qualify it with the table name. I'll update the answer.

Comment: mmm... that has the same effect.  no change.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd do it like this:

```
Borough.joins(:events).where(:events => {:day_of_week => 2})
```

Rails will use an inner join by default, so it'll exclude any Boroughs that don't have a matching event. You don't actually need place data at all for the query as described.

Comment: Yes, it should be on the Borough class instead of the Event class.

Answer (score 2):

As of Rails 3.2, try [Pluck](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck)

```
Event.where(:events => {:day_of_week => 2}).joins(:borough).uniq.pluck('boroughs.name')
```

Should work.

If you're planning on chaining it with a scope be forewarned, lazy loading will cause it not to work as intended, instead do something like

```
def self.somemethod
  joins(:borough).pluck('boroughs.name').uniq
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, alias the column name,

```
select("DISTINCT boroughs.name as borough_name")
```

Then access that name as a field.

```
events = Event.where(day_of_week: 2).joins(:place,:borough).select("DISTINCT boroughs.name as borough_name")
events.map{|event| event.borough_name}
```